# Copying file path from GUI to the command line

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, copy-and-paste

When I copy a file path from the GUI (right-click on file and press 'Copy') and then paste it in the command line (Ctrl + Shift + V), it shows as:

```
file:///home/user/Documents/file.ext
```

I would like it to show as:

```
/home/user/Documents/file.ext
```

Is there a shortcut for this? I work a lot with images and it is a bit cumbersome to always manually delete 'file://'.

Comment: @karel Thanks for your reply. However the answers on this post make this action not more efficient for me. I would prefer a short-cut instead of 'Ctrl+Shift+V'.

Comment: Are you copying from the default Nautilus file manager to the default Gnome Terminal? or some other GUI application(s)?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, I am! Default for both.

Comment: OK I couldn't reproduce this on 18.04 - it seems to be a recent change. See for example [Nautilus no longer copies file path when a file is marked then copied](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1826266) and [Copy path of directory or file to clipboard](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/634)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of Files (nautilus) 3.32, the clipboard operation has changed to accommodate the Gnome Shell "Desktop Icons" extension. As a result, copying a file will fill the clipboard with

```
x-special/nautilus-clipboard
copy
file:///home/user/Documents/299867.jpg
```

rather than, like before, just the path name:

```
/home/user/Documents/299867.jpg
```

Power users thus can no longer conveniently copy paste the pathname from Files to a terminal or editor, or a File - Open/Save dialog.

The issue [has been filed with Gnome](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/634). You can work around by installing either a Nautilus Python extension or a Nautilus script.

**Nautilus Python extension**

`+` Nicely integrated
`+` Quick right-click mouse access
`-` No hotkey

If just using the mouse to copy the path is OK for you, it is sufficient to install the python extension [`nautilus-copypath`](https://github.com/ronen25/nautilus-copypath). It provides you with a right-click menu item to copy the path, but does not provide the ability to achieve that with a hotkey.

**Nautilus script**

`+` Hotkey access
`-` Two clicks required
`-` Less "integrated"

Power users prefer to keep their hands on the keyboard, though. While Python extensions are neatly integrated, there is no easy way (that I discovered) to assign them a keyboard shortcut or at least a menu accelerator key. In contrast, one can easily assign a hotkey to a nautilus script. The drawback is that one more click is required to select the entry with the mouse. To have both optimal keyboard access and optimal mouse access, you can always install both the script and the Python extension.

**1. Create a nautilus scripts folder.** If not yet available, create a nautilus `scripts` folder under `.local/share/nautilus`. To see the hidden `.local` folder in Files, select "Show hidden files" (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>). Any executable scripts you put in that folder will appear in a "Scripts" menu that will appear in your right-click menu of Files.

**2. Create a script to copy the file path.** Open your text editor, paste following text

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | perl -pe 'chomp if eof' | xsel -b -i
```

The `perl` construct is there to remove the last hard return.

Save the text file in the nautilus scripts folder (`.local/share/nautilus/scripts`) with the name `Copy Path`. You can choose any file name, but be aware that the file name is what will appear as entry under your Scripts menu. Close your editor.

**3. Make the script executable.** Right-click the script file in Files, select "Properties" (or just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> with the file selected) and on the "Permissions" tab, check "Execute:".

**4. Add a hotkey for the function.** With your text editor, open, or create if it does not yet exist, a file `.config/nautilus/scripts-accels` (i.e., a file named `script-accels` in the folder `nautilus` under the hidden folder `.config`. Add a line to define the hotkey you want to use to copy the pathname. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, so I added a line as:

```
<Control><Shift>c Copy Path
```

Close that file. You need to fully restart Files for the script to become available.

**5. Make sure `xsel` is installed**. `xsel` is a command line tool to manipulate the contents of the clipboard. It is not installed by default, so you may need to install it for the nautilus script to work: `sudo apt install xsel`.

Comment: I had to install `xsel` for the script to work `sudo apt-get install xsel`

Comment: I will add indeed that `xsel` is not installed by default. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution is to run first <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, and then your usual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/ <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, which is the suggested workaround on the [bug issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/634)

Comment: This only works for the file folder path. It's not a workaround to get the full path of the file (which is usually what you want).

Answer (score 2):

As Ubuntu 21.10 and Nautilus 40. We don't need to use any script to do the trick, just need to Ctrl + C and and Ctrl + Shift + V.

Or Drag and Drop the file to Gnome Terminal :D

Answer (score 0):

It's not the answer for your question, but installing another great file manager as Thunar you could have this functionality back.

```
apt-get install thunar
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Thunar file manager with `sudo apt install thunar`.
2. Install xclip.
3. In Thunar go to *Edit* -> *Configure custom actions* -> click *Add*
4. In *Create Action* -> set "Name" for command
5. In *Command* set this command: " echo -n %f | xclip -selection clipboard "